# 90s SciFi TV show, pilot/marine searches for his sister who landed on an alien planet before him

Tags: story-identification, tv

I have looked everywhere but can't find a TV show I am having flashbacks of! Here is what I remember

- Based in space on an alien planet
- there is conflict with any alien race
- the main character is a pilot? Marine?
- the big thing I remember is the main character's sister is missing, she landed on the planet before him. Finding her is the long-running story arc
- late nineties, aired on a major network
- the whole series felt like it was filmed at night

Comment: live-action or animated? what language? what country did you watch it in? was it aimed at any age group?

Comment: Sounds vaguely like "Space: Above and Beyond", at least if one substitutes  "fiancé" for "sister".

Comment: @Eike nailed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, this is almost certainly [Space: Above and Beyond](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112173/).

- Based in space on an alien planet

The main characters were based on a "space carrier" the USS Saratoga, but many episodes were set on alien planets

- there is conflict with any alien race

The Chigs

- the main character is a pilot? Marine?

The main characters were members of the 58th Squadron Space Aviator Cavalry, United States Marine Corps

- the big thing I remember is the main characters sister is missing, she landed on the planet before him. Finding her is the long running story arc

Lt. Nathan West had a fiance who travelled to a colony world that was then attacked by the aliens before he arrived.

- late nineties aired on a major network

First screened on the FOX network in the USA between 1994 and 1996

- the whole series felt like it was filmed at night

There were a lot of scenes in space and a some on alien worlds at night